# Appium for mobile automation testing for android

Tags: android, appium

I am facing problem in appium for android app that a new session could not be created. 
Original error:

> Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make
>   sure it exists and is a launchable activity.

WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This means the app activity u have given i wrong. Copy the apk to ur windows machine and run the below command in cmd prompt,

```
aapt dump badging "full path to ur apk file"
```

It will result lots of logs. look for the below string `launchable activity-"ur apk's activity name"`

Take that and replace it in ur capability in code. this will work

Answer (score 0):

Give correct path to apk file in your windows after that once you restart the eclipse and try again this will solve your problem.